# How to access the MuleSoft Mule Management Console (MMC) REST API?

Tags: mulesoft

How can we access the MuleSoft's Mule Management Console (MMC) RESTful API?

They provided the URL "http://localhost:8585/mmc-console-3.7.3/api/deployments". and ask us to download the mmc.war file but that file is not available.

They won't be provide the IP Address to access that REST API.

Comment: Who is 'they'? What version of Mule are you using?

Comment: Asking where to get a proprietary software is not an appropriate question for Stackoverflow.com so I'll answer that part here, You need to be a MuleSoft customer and login into their Help Center site (help.mulesoft.com). Having said that MMC is end of life, obsolete, and it a security risk to use.

Answer (score 0):

First, note that Mule Management Console (MMC) has been deprecated in 2015 and it has been End of Life since 2019. Using it is a security risk, since it has not been been updated in years for any bugs nor security vulnerabilities. Also it is not compatible with any current version of Mule Runtime, so it will be useful only for older versions that are end of life too. This is mentioned at the top of [MMC's documentation](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-management-console/3.8/).

Additionally, if for some reason you still want to use MMC it is recommended to use the last available MMC 3.8.x version compatible with your Mule runtime version. See the last releases notes at https://docs.mulesoft.com/release-notes/mule-mmc/mule-management-console. Be aware as mentioned above that these versions have been released years ago.

The MMC URL depends on the name the application had at deployment time into a Java Web Container (same as any other .war file), the host:port where the Web Container is deployed, and the credentials for authentication. You need to be provided these pieces of information by whoever installed MMC. This is mentioned in the [assumptions section of MMC documentation](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-management-console/3.8/rest-api-reference#assumptions).

Depending on your particular server and installation it may different. For example if you are using a Tomcat instance in your local computer configured to listen to port `8932` and renamed MMC .war file to `mymmc.war`, and the resource of the API you want to use is `deployments`, then the URL will `http://localhost:8932/mymmc/api/deployments`.

For a full list of resources see the [reference](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-management-console/3.8/rest-api-reference).